# How do I have sbt's Jetty use a local domain name?

Tags: scala, jetty, lift, sbt

I'd like the version of Jetty launched by `sbt> ~jetty` to listen on `my.name.local`, which I've set to `127.0.0.1` in `/etc/hosts`. It [seems to be possible](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/simple-build-tool/sSr5pwwz-DU/discussion) to change Jetty's settings from within sbt.

Here's what I have for my project:

```
import sbt._

class LiftProject(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultWebProject(info) {
  // ...

  val jetty = "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "7.3.0.v20110203" % "test"

  override lazy val jettyInstance = new JettyRunner(customJettyConfiguration) 

  def customJettyConfiguration = { 
    val myLog = log 
    val myJettyClasspath = jettyClasspath 
    val myScanDirectories = scanDirectories
    val myScanInterval = scanInterval

    new CustomJettyConfiguration { 
      def classpath = jettyRunClasspath
      def jettyClasspath = myJettyClasspath
      def war = jettyWebappPath
      def contextPath = jettyContextPath
      def classpathName = "test"
      def parentLoader = buildScalaInstance.loader
      def scanDirectories = Path.getFiles(myScanDirectories).toSeq
      def scanInterval = myScanInterval
      def port = jettyPort
      def log = myLog      
      override def jettyConfigurationXML = 
        <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
          <Set name="virtualHosts">
            <Array type="java.lang.String">
              <Item>my.name.local</Item>
            </Array>
          </Set>
        </Configure>
    }
  }
}
```

While it seems to launch without complaints, visiting `my.name.local` doesn't hit Jetty as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than running sbt as root (dangerous), I personally prefer rerouting port 80 to 8080 using iptables on Linux :

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Which works only until the next reboot. To make the setting persistent on Ubuntu 10.04, I use :

```
sudo bash -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"
echo "#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
exit 0
" > /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload
echo "#!/bin/sh
iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules
if [ -f /etc/iptables.downrules ]; then
   iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.downrules
fi
exit 0
" > /etc/network/if-post-down.d/iptablessave
chmod +x /etc/network/if-post-down.d/iptablessave
chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptablesload
```

(see [this Ubuntu iptables wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo))

Comment: Nice, that's better than my solution. Since I'm on OS X, it looks like the program is called `ipfw`.

Comment: nevermind.. I found the answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13755/how-to-reset-all-iptables-settings

Answer (score 1):

I posted too soon. All I need to do is override `jettyPort`:

```
override def jettyPort = 80
```

And run `sbt` via `sudo`.